# Twitter API followers/ids - All Followers Returned but next_cursor is still present

Tags: api, twitter

I have been working with the Twitter API [followers/ids] for a few of our accounts but recent got stuck with a confusing state.

Usually twitter returns a next_cursor when there are still some records remaining in next page(s). It works fine with iteration but recently when I tried to request followers/ids for one of our accounts which doesn't have a lot of followers (just over 4200) and all can be returned in single request. Even though, the API returns all the followers in a single request but strangely the **next_cursor** is still present.

So when I try to make another (2nd) request with that **cursor**, only one record is returned which is not present in the first set of records.

What should I consider that how much followers the user actually have?

```
Total Followers: 4224
1st Request: 4224 [next_cursor: present]
2nd Request with cursor: 1
```

This is creating confusion as it is 4224 or 4225?

Attaching a screenshot
[image]